# ExpandableListView's inside a ScrollView won't scroll

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

So i got this really annoying issue. I have got `ExpandableListView's` inside a `ScrollView` inside a`RelativeLayout` and when the `ExpandableListView's` are open(Expand) it's like the `ScrollView` won't work and i can't scroll to get to my lower View's.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
tools:context="com.example.activity.Activity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emai_to_send_to_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/emai_to_send_to_text_view_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emai_to_send_to_edit_text_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/emai_to_send_to_edit_text_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/emai_to_send_to_id"
    />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/opening_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/emai_to_send_to_edit_text_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/opening_words_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/opening_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_header_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/name_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/opening_words_text_view_id"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_edit_text_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/name_edit_text_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/name_header_text_view_id"
    />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/something_i_hate_about_you_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/name_edit_text_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/something_i_hate_about_you_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/something_i_hate_about_you_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    />

 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/hope_you_will_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/something_i_hate_about_you_text_view_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hope_you_will_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/hope_you_will_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/ps_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/hope_you_will_text_view_id"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ps_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/initial_text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/ps_expandable_list_view_id"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/your_name_header_text_view_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/your_name_text"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/opening_words_list_view_header_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/ps_text_view_id"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/your_name_edit_text_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/your_name_edit_text_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/selection_text_color"
    android:layout_below="@id/your_name_header_text_view_id"
    />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/send_email_button_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/send_email_button_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/your_name_edit_text_id"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also in this layout i got a warning on the opening `ScrollView` - `This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless`

I can upload pictures if youd like. Please if anyone can help it will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please, **avoid** nested Scrollable Views!!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks for the answer. But how do i get to scroll a lot of `ExpandableListView's` even when they are open?

Comment: Better not to have them all on the same window.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein So how do i get ExpandableListVIew to Scroll?

Comment: It's automatic. When it grows over the available screen height, it becomes scrollable. Every scrollable View behaves the same way.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yeah but i dont mean to the children in the ExpandableScrollView i mean to the View's inside my RelativeLayout.

Comment: Then, you better rethink your UI and have the ExpandableListView be opened in a secondary window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88318/discussion-between-god-and-frank-n-stein).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Another activity? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. Or a DialogFragment (even better).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Although i didnt got an answer ' thanks for your help man.

Comment: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/android-dialogfragment-listview.html

Comment: There is also a video tutorial (the speaker's English is awful, but...): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yikx61n3oxE

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as i studied the issue(and i studied it a lot) you can't get `View's` to scroll when the `ExpandableListView` is on it's open state.